# How can I approach proving this?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, proof-writing

I'm currently trying to formulate an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof for the following multi=variable limit:

[image]

What I've got so far is very little, and just a formality thing:

Let $\space \varepsilon > 0.$ We wish to find a $\delta >0$ such that if $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$, then $|y\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - 0| < \varepsilon$

This is where I'm stuck. I can't seem to pinpoint where to go from here to find something to begin my inequalities to get some expression of $\delta$ from the original function, $y\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Can I get some hints or leads on how to approach this proof?

Comment: Hint: What is the range of $|\sin x|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, use $$\left|\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|\leq1$$

Comment: So if I split the absolute value into $|y|\cdot|\sin(\frac{1}{x})|$ and then use that inequality, I can say $|y|\cdot|\sin(\frac{1}{x})| \leqslant |y| = \sqrt{y^2} < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$ and then set $\varepsilon = \delta$?

Comment: @Pixel Rain Yes, I think. We can assume $\delta=\epsilon.$

Comment: And that will complete my proof?

Comment: @Pixel Rain Yes of course.

Comment: @Pixel Rain  You can say also that $x\neq0$.  I mean we can not take points like $(0,y)$, where $y\rightarrow0^+$.

Comment: @Barry Cipra It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\left|y\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-0\right|<|y|$$ and the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $$|y\sin(\frac1x)| = |y||\sin(\frac1x)|,$$ the fact that $$|y|\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and the fact that $|\sin(\alpha)|\leq 1$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb R$.